# Discontinuity between java.util.regex.Matcher.group and string comparison

Tags: java, regex

All I want to do is load information I saved to a plain text file about the position of a [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) and set the frame to the state it was saved as. For some reason I'm unable to compare capture groups with strings; that is, `matcher.group("state")` compared to the string it should be (`"min"`, `"max"`, or `"normal"`) is not returning true, and the same goes with `matcher.group("vis")`.

```
String fileArrayStr = "WINDOW_LAYOUT:0,0|779x768|max|show"
```

My code is:

```
byte[] fileArray = null;
String fileArrayStr = null;
try {
    fileArray = Files.readAllBytes(PathToConfig);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    fileArrayStr = new String(fileArray, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// checking the value of fileArrayStr here by outputting it
// confirms the data is read correctly from the file

pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "WINDOW_LAYOUT:\\s*" +
    "(?<x>[0-9\\-]+),(?<y>[0-9\\-]+)\\|" +
    "(?<length>\\d+)x(?<height>\\d+)\\|" +
    "(?<state>[minaxorl]+)\\|" +
    "(?<vis>[showide]+)\\s*");
matcher = pattern.matcher(fileArrayStr);
if (matcher.find()) {
    frame.setLocation(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("x")),
                    Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("y")));
    frame.setSize(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("length")),
                    Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("height")));
    DialogMsg("state: " + matcher.group("state") + "\n" + "vis: "
                    + matcher.group("vis"));

    // the above DialogMsg call (my own function to show a popup dialog)
    // shows the
    // data is being read correctly, as the values are "max" and "show"
    // for state
    // and vis, respectively. Same with the DialogMsg calls below.

    if (matcher.group("state") == "min") {
        try {
            frame.setIcon(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (matcher.group("state") == "max") {
        try {
            frame.setMaximum(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        DialogMsg("matcher.group(\"state\") = \""
                        + matcher.group("state") + "\"");
    }
    if (matcher.group("vis") == "show") {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } else if (matcher.group("vis") == "hide") {
        frame.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        DialogMsg("matcher.group(\"vis\") = \"" + matcher.group("vis")
                        + "\"");
    }
}
```

The code is always falling back to the `else` statements. What am I doing wrong? [matcher.group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28java.lang.String%29) is supposed to return a string, is it not?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by format my code. It is already formatted. And definitely not a duplicate. Just because two questions may have the same answer does not mean the question itself is a duplicate...

Comment: It is hard to read code when it is all on one line. Format it so that one statement = 1 line. You don't know how to compare String values and that's why your code isn't expecting as you want it to. This is a duplicate without you knowing it.

Comment: I suppose we differ then, in our philosophy of being a moderator here. But thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if( matcher.group("state") == "min" )
```

to

```
if( matcher.group("state").equals("min") )
```

You don't use `==` to compare `Strings`. You should use [.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) or [.equalsIgnoresCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the string by "==" operator which will compare the objects so the condition gets false and it goes to the else portion of your code. So in place of "==" operator try to use .equals or .equalsIgnoresCase method.